# Import Modules to Pyscript

Tags: python, html, import, package, pyscript

When we are coding python code, we typically use packages and modules that we import. For example, when we are coding we may write:

```
import numpy
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

When we are trying to integrate python with html with Pyscript (https://pyscript.net/), it just says that it doesn’t have the package installed. However, when this happens in normal python we use PiP and import it from there. However, what should we do when we need a package in Pyscript?

Thank you!

Comment: it seems someone already answered this. If you see [examples](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/tree/main/pyscriptjs/examples) then you see `<py-env>`  which defines what modules can be used. If I tried to use non-existing module then I saw it error that it can't find it on `https://pypi.org` (and probably it loads modules directly from this server). And as I expected some modules may not work because they may use C/C++ libraries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At this time, **bs4** is not supported. You will receive an error

> ValueError: Couldn't find a pure Python 3 wheel for 'bs4'

You will also have problems using the requests package in pyscript. Use`pyfetch` instead of `requests.get`.

To import numpy and requests, use `<py-env>` before `<py-script>`. Example:

```
<body>
  <py-env>
  - numpy
  </py-env>

  <py-script>

import numpy as np

print(np.random.randn(10, 4))

</py-script>
</body>
```

Pyscript also supports package versions:

```
  <py-env>
    - numpy==1.22.3
  </py-env>
```

Comment: FYI it appears that a lot changed since this answer was posted. I added a new one.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like py-env has been deprecated (I couldn't get it to work at all). Fortunately, py-config did the trick:

```
  <py-config type="toml">
    packages = ["numpy", "beautifulsoup4", "requests"]
  </py-config>

  <py-script>
        import numpy as np
        import requests
        import bs4
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

        print(bs4.__version__)
        print(requests.__version__)

        a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
        print("Array:", a)
        print("Hello from Python in the browser!")
  </py-script>
```

Comment: This did the trick for me too