# Pyscript-ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: html, pyscript

I'm making weather website with pyscript but i got this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' so  i wrote import requests and i downloaded this requests module from cmd but it still says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' how do i fix this error?

`inline code`

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <py-script src="main.py"></py-script>
    <input id="getweather" placeholder="search weather...">
    <button id="btngwt" pys-onClick="play_game">sipal</button>
    <h1 id="babo"></h1>
    
</body>
</html>




import requests
import json

search = Element("getweather")
something = Element("babo")

def play_game(*args):
    wt = search.value
    city = wt #도시 
    apiKey = "db1e8e28d93cbbabad4f0162fa37dbdf"
    lang = 'kr' #언어
    units = 'metric' #화씨 온도를 섭씨 온도로 변경
    api = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={apiKey}&lang={lang}&units={units}"

    result = requests.get(api)
    result = json.loads(result.text)

    something.element.innerText = f"{result}"```
````

Comment: I don't think requests can work in a web context, there might be pyscript specific options for HTTP but they are going to be much more complex

Comment: See John Hanley's comments about 'requests' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72120030/8508004). Keep in mind about the installation part that the conventions have evolved since that answer was posted, see about `py-config` in current documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not specific to Python/PyScript. The web browser sandbox (virtual machine) does not provide a TCP socket API. Therefore, Python packages such as `requests` will not work. You will need to modify your application to use supported browser HTTP methods such as the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).